# Build and debug a CLion project over ssh

Tags: c++, c, clion

I am developing something for the raspberry pi. I have ssh connection to the PI (running an IDE like CLion on the PI directly would be way too heavy). I would really appreciate having the graphical debugger of CLion however, so I'm trying to figure out how I can setup CLion to build and debug over ssh. What I found on their website only talks about deployment:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html

Is this possible and if yes where can I read how to do it?

Comment: CLion doesn't have an ability to build remotely (via ssh) for now. But it has remote debug via gdb server: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/07/clion-2016-2-eap-remote-gdb-debug/

Comment: @nastasiak2512 Thank you. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it as there isn't much else to add!

Comment: You can work in WSL on windows though, which is POSIX-compliant. I develop for Linux in WSL and it works well.